# retain html div elements after updatepanel update in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, dom, updatepanel, facebox

I use jquery facebox as delete confirmation box. When i do a delete it removes my record and i show the resultsdiv via javascript. But it always shows

`Error: document.getElementById("ImageButtonDiv") is null`

here is my code,

```
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // my delete
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Delete, typeof(Button), "dele", 
          "ShowImageButtonDiv();topBar('Successfully Deleted');", true);
}
```

and my javascript function,

```
function ShowImageButtonDiv() {
    document.getElementById("ImageButtonDiv").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("datatable").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("adddiv").style.display = 'none';
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

When my delete confirmation is not within a jquery facebox it gets my element. What could be the issue?

I ve replaced but still not working,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(LbDelete, typeof(LinkButton), "dele", 
 "jQuery(document).ready(function(){UsersDatatable('" + HfJsonString.Value + "');
        ShowImageButtonDiv();topBar('Successfully Deleted');});", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happened because your script is probably run before the dom is ready so he can not find the ImageButtonDiv.

You can change that by place this code to run when dom is ready
For example.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Delete, typeof(Button), "dele", 
          "jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ShowImageButtonDiv();topBar('Successfully Deleted'); });"
, true);
```

Comment: @Pandiya Sorry, I use the jQuery for compatibility reasons. The $ is the same as jQuery when not make the switch to compatibility